# Toshiba Thrive, changing system font

Tags: system, fonts, toshiba-ac100

I am currently running the Favum 1.1 ROM on my toshiba thrive, and I tried to use Font Installer to install a new system font. For some reason the font will install, but the actual font on my thrive won't change even when I restart and wipe the davlik cache. Is there any way to change the system font?

I can't find the system/font folder anywhere either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GB 2.3, the fonts folder is located in /system/fonts, how it works is this, for a font face, it copies the fonts to the original droid fonts names at the same time retaining the pre-defined font names in place.

In my rom, I have this, from adb shell,

```
sh-4.1# cd /system/fonts
sh-4.1# ls -l
-rw-r--r-- root     root         4824 2012-06-13 16:49 Clockopia.ttf
-rw-r--r-- root     root        86784 2012-06-13 16:49 DroidSans-Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r-- root     root        74656 2012-06-13 16:49 DroidSans.ttf
-rw-r--r-- root     root      3725920 2012-06-13 16:49 DroidSansFallback.ttf
-rw-r--r-- root     root       119380 2012-06-13 16:49 DroidSansMono.ttf
-rw-r--r-- root     root       185228 2012-06-13 16:49 DroidSerif-Bold.ttf
-rw-r--r-- root     root       190304 2012-06-13 16:49 DroidSerif-BoldItalic.ttf
-rw-r--r-- root     root       177560 2012-06-13 16:49 DroidSerif-Italic.ttf
-rw-r--r-- root     root       172916 2012-06-13 16:49 DroidSerif-Regular.ttf
```

Notice how the names are retained but are in fact Roboto fonts! :)

Sounds like the fonts are installed into a different name in which the ROM is not picking it up. For example, suppose the font's name is 'MyFont.ttf' and that gets copied over, but is not copied into 'DroidSans.ttf'... just a guess.

BTW, what Android is that ROM you're referring to?

***Edit:*** It has been ascertained that this is Honeycomb (Android 3.2.1). Do the following:

1. Plug in cable to Toshiba Thrive
2. From command line, issue this, **adb shell ls /system/fonts**
3. Select all the text of that output, copy to clipboard, and go to http://www.pastebin.com and create a new paste, paste in the contents and it will create a linky for everyone to see, put that linky into the comments below and will look at it :)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138100/discussion-on-answer-by-t0mm13b-toshiba-thrive-changing-system-font).

Answer (score 1):

I use [Rom Toolbox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jrummy.liberty.toolbox&hl=en) for this. Swipe left twice to get to the `Interface` section and chose `Font Installer`. If you're rooted, you'll see the new font after a reboot/hot restart.

Comment: That still didn't change the font... I granted it superuser permissions, installed a font, the restarted. Still no change.

Comment: hmmm.. a conundrum. Perhaps Favum ROM uses fonts from a different than default location? Will look..

Comment: Or maybe I could add a font folder..?

Comment: you probably have to locate the existing one.

Comment: Have you tried actually looking for font files .ttf, etc? By issing find / -name *.ttf in a shell?

Comment: I have not, will try that now